# Wordpress Plugin auto create Parent page and childs to related parent

Tags: php, wordpress

i developed an WordPress plugin,it is a complex plugin,a nd now what remained to do i want to create a Page Parent and Child Pages that belongs to Page Parent.

My code for page creation is below, first function will create a parent page, and second function is also creating a parent page, i can not make a child of the first page, there is post_parent but how to get the id of that page parent that i create first?

```html
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_page_1_parent');

function create_page_1_parent()
{
    //post status and options
    $post = array(
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'ping_status' =>  'closed' ,
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_name' => '1first post',
        'post_status' => 'publish' ,
        'post_title' => 'parent',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => '',
        'post_content' => '[il_login_form]'
    );
    //insert page and save the id
    $newvalue = wp_insert_post( $post, false );
    //save the id in the database
    update_option( 'hclpage', $newvalue );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_page_1_parent_child');

function create_page_1_parent_child()
{
    //post status and options
    $post = array(
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'ping_status' =>  'closed' ,
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_name' => '1first post',
        'post_status' => 'publish' ,
        'post_title' => 'parent',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => '', //what i have to put here that will go udner parent page
        'post_content' => '[il_login_form]'
    );
    //insert page and save the id
    $newvalue = wp_insert_post( $post, false );
    //save the id in the database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do both of the inserts in 1 function.

```
function create_page_1_parent()
{
    //post status and options
    $post = array(
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'ping_status' =>  'closed' ,
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_name' => '1first post',
        'post_status' => 'publish' ,
        'post_title' => 'parent',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => '',
        'post_content' => '[il_login_form]'
    );
    //insert page and save the id
    $newvalue = wp_insert_post( $post, false );
    //save the id in the database
    update_option( 'hclpage', $newvalue );

    //post status and options
    $post = array(
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'ping_status' =>  'closed' ,
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_name' => '1first post',
        'post_status' => 'publish' ,
        'post_title' => 'parent',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => $newvalue, //what i have to put here that will go udner parent page
        'post_content' => '[il_login_form]'
    );
    //insert page and save the id
    $newvalue = wp_insert_post( $post, false );
    //save the id in the database
}
```